# Wait for all ajax calls to terminate in selenium webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement a function that allows me to wait for any running (jQuery) ajax call to terminate in a selenium webdriverjs test environment.
My current working assumption is that I need to properly integrate the following elements:

- Use `WebDriver.wait` to actually wait for the condition
- Use `$(document).ajaxStop(function () {...});` to determine if all ajax calls are terminated
- Use `WebDriver.executeAsyncScript` to invoke the needed JavaScript code in the browser

I imagine something like this:

```
const PREPARE_SCRIPT = 'window.ajax_running = false;
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {window.ajax_running = true;});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {window.ajax_running = false;});';
driver.executeAsyncScript(PREPARE_SCRIPT)
driver.wait(function () {
   return driver.executeAsyncScript('return window.ajax_running === false;');
});
```

Unfortunately I do not seem to have the needed experience to get all the needed elements to work together or I might just be on the wrong track altogether and there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the executeScript (in synchronous mode). Use console.log to debug (tested with Chrome).

Below the official javadoc:
http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html

Below is a snippet:

```
 driver.executeScript("window.ajax_running = true;");
 driver.executeScript("$(document).ajaxStart(function () 
       {console.log(\"ajaxStart\"); window.ajax_running = true;});");
 driver.executeScript("$(document).ajaxStop(function () 
       {console.log(\"ajaxStop\"); window.ajax_running = false;});");
 sysout(driver.executeScript("return window.ajax_running"));
```

HTH